# selecting the same data in different row from database

Tags: sql, database

[image]

i need to select the 'name' attributes must same value with 'seek' attribute.
is kind like a match making concept which i need to select the 'name' attribute = 'seek' attribute in same table
so the outcome will be

```
name      | seek
HEADPHONE | KETTLE
KETTLE    | HEADPHONE
```

anyone can give me the solution on how to do it. i currently doing my final year project. Thank you

Comment: Instead of posting image post the data in text format

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.NAME,
       t1.SEEK
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.NAME = t2.SEEK AND
       t1.SEEK = t2.NAME
```

If you want to report only one record for each `SEEK`/`NAME` pair, then you can try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEAST(t1.NAME, t1.SEEK),
                GREATEST(t1.NAME, t1.SEEK)
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.NAME = t2.SEEK AND
       t1.SEEK = t2.NAME
```

Comment: why i get error group function is not allowed here. I need only one record for each seek/name

Comment: @FYP I updated my answer to give you only one record.

Comment: feel free to look my new question it quite similar but a little bit changes have been made

Comment: @FYP No, don't do this, rather open a new question.

Comment: i already open a new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391966/sql-queries-to-find-the-match-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform `SELF JOIN`

```
SELECT a.NAME, 
       a.seek 
FROM   yourtable a 
       JOIN yourtable b 
         ON a.NAME = b.seek 
            AND b.NAME = a.seek
```

Another approach would be using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT a.NAME, 
       a.seek
FROM   yourtable a 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   yourtable b 
               WHERE  a.NAME = b.seek 
                      AND b.NAME = a.seek)
```