# sql queries to find the match attributes

Tags: sql, oracle

i am currently doing a system like bartering system. the situation like this . A customer (Jasmine) require to input the 'NAME' attribute (what she have to seek) and input the'SEEK' attribute (what she need to seek). In order to get the result, the 'SEEK' attribute must match with 'Name' attribute from other customer and the 'SEEK' attribute from other customer must match with 'HAVE' attribute from Jasmine.

for example i have table items (already in database)

```
|ITEMSID|NAME   |SEEK     |USERID|
|A01    |printer|laptop   |A1    |
|A45    |laptop |headphone|A2    |
|AY3    |laptop |headphone|A3    |
```

For example Jasmine has 'Name' attribute headphone and 'Seek' attribute laptop and the result should like this. The result should list out all possibility (it may consists more than one row depends, and it may get zero result if the are no match betwen 'NAME' AND  'SEEK' attribute

```
|ITEMSID|NAME   |SEEK     |USERID|
|AY3    |laptop |headphone|A3    |
|A45    |laptop |headphone|A2    |
```

Thank you for helping me. The system that i'm being develop using jsp
p/s: i'm a new user in stackoverflow.

EDIT based on comments:

I already tried using an `inner join` but the query result is not specific on one transaction (mean the result match between 'Have' and 'Seek' attribute, but has all the matching rows and not the choose the 'Have' attribute that being input):

```
SELECT a.NAME, a.seek,a.ITEMSID 
FROM items a 
JOIN items b ON a.NAME = b.seek AND b.NAME = a.seek
```

Comment: Did you try to write a query for this? What did you try so far? What went wrong?

Comment: i already try using a inner join but the query result does not specific on one transaction (mean the result match between 'Have' and 'Seek' attribute read all the each row and not the choose the'Have' attribute that being input')

Comment: SELECT a.NAME, 
       a.seek,a.ITEMSID
FROM   items a 
       JOIN items b 
         ON a.NAME = b.seek 
            AND b.NAME = a.seek

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oracle sql developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the query you have tried, if I understand your request correctly (not sure I do), all you are missing is the `WHERE` clause for the input.

```
SELECT a.name, a.seek, a.ITEMSID 
FROM items a 
JOIN items b 
  ON a.name = b.seek 
  AND b.name = a.seek
WHERE a.name = 'input here'
```

Comment: tq, i already try this query but the result is not what i target to get it. The query display what the first customer input( in a given example Jasmine 'name' and 'seek' attribute

Comment: @FYP - 'Name' is Jasmine? In your sample data name had values like 'headphones'... Please post sample data and the required sample output.